# What is the difference between Pass and None in Python

Tags: python, keyword, semantics

I would personally like to know the semantic difference between using Pass and None. I could not able to find any difference in execution.

PS: I could not able to find any similar questions in SO. If you find one, please point it out.

Thanks!

Comment: Just to add some more details: What is the difference between method 1 and method2:

method1:
for i in range(10):
    if i == 6:
        None
        print("hola!!")
    print(i)

method2:
for i in range(10):
    if i == 6:
        pass
        print("hola!!")
    print(i)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[`pass`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-pass-statement) is a **statement**. As such it can be used everywhere a statement can be used to do nothing.

[`None`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#None) is an [atom](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html) and as such an **expression** in its simplest form. It is also a keyword and a constant value for “nothing” (the only instance of the `NoneType`). Since it is an expression, it is valid in every place an expression is expected.

Usually, `pass` is used to signify an empty function body as in the following example:

```
def foo():
    pass
```

This function does nothing since its only statement is the no-operation statement `pass`.

Since an expression is also a valid function body, you could also write this using `None`:

```
def foo():
    None
```

While the function will behave identically, it is a bit different since the expression (while constant) will still be evaluated (although immediately discarded).

Comment: Thank you @poke, that's the exact difference I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

In simple terms, `None` is a value that you can assign to a variable that signifies emptiness. It can be useful as a default state:

```
a = None
def f():
   a = 5
f()
```

`pass` is a statement that is like a nop. It can be useful when you are defining function stubs, for instance:

```
def f():
    pass
```

In C-like languages, you would be able to define empty functions by simply putting nothing between the braces `void f() { }`, but since Python uses indentation instead of braces to define blocks, you must put *something* in the body, and `pass` is the idiomatic thing to put there.

Comment: Wow! This's a good explain "In C-like languages, you would be able to define empty functions by simply putting nothing between the braces void f() { }, but since Python uses indentation instead of braces to define blocks, you must put something in the body, and pass is the idiomatic thing to put there." Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's absolute difference between `pass` and `None`

**The `pass` (without upper case P)**:

Because python be the indent base language, so if you define a new method, you should have some code after that.

```
def method_a():
    some_thing = 1  # Have to do some thing
```

If not, an exception should be raised so you could use the `pass` keyword for hacks this problem.

```
def method_a():
    pass  # Do nothing
```

**The `None`**:

So very different, the `None` keyword has a little bit same to the `null` keywords from another language like Java or C. That may be the empty data or not assign data like that.

```
[] == None
null == None
() == None
...
```