# Is there any reason using pass in favourable over None as empty statement

Tags: python

I came across a legacy code base, which is using `pass`, and `None` interchange, as empty statement.

```
if True:
    pass
```

---

```
if True:
    None
```

Since we prefer to have a consistent style over our code base, we wish to stick with one common standard. We need to choose between `pass` and `None`.

Python community mostly recommend using `pass` as empty statement.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15081801/1051441

But, is there any side effect if we use `None`?

Is there any reason using `pass` in favourable over `None` as empty statement?

[What is the difference between Pass and None in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47973242/what-is-the-difference-between-pass-and-none-in-python) talks about difference among the 2. But, it doesn't mention why `pass` is preferable over `None` as empty statement.

Comment: `pass` exists explicitly for this purpose. `None` exists for a different purpose. Use `pass`.

Comment: `None` is a statement creating and immediately discarding a `None` value. `pass` simply is a NOOP.

Comment: @deceze well, `None` is actually a singleton, so, there is no creation/deletion. It simply loads a constant onto the stack.

Comment: @juanpa Fair enough, but same difference. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `pass` is better.

Technically, in your example, there is no difference. Both snippets have the same disassembly:

(note that in fact, the function does absolutely nothing. The `LOAD CONST None` is for an implicit return statement, returning `None`.)

```
>>> def f():
...     if True:
...         pass
...
>>> def g():
...     if True:
...         None
...
>>> dis.dis(f)
  3           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              2 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(g)
  3           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              2 RETURN_VALUE
```

However, it's important to consider readability of your code. The statement `None` and `pass` essentially mean different things. `pass` is a [placeholder](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-pass-statement), `None` is a [data value](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy). It is merely a coincidence that having `None` by itself does nothing. It is better to **code what you mean**.

Comment: Is that not what I exactly said?

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, appreciate that!

Answer (score 1):

As other answers mentioned, there is no difference in the meaning of the code. Furthermore, recent versions of CPython enables dead code elimination on these kind of examples, and the bytecode is exactly the same in the OP's examples.

However, here's a very slight performance difference, in particular in earlier versions without optimization.  Namely, when Python hits the `pass` keyword *statement*, it just jumps over it. But when it hits the `None` *expression*, it loads the value and then discards it, with the implied increment and decrement of reference count. Therefore, the latter should be slightly slower.

Example:

```bash
$ python -m timeit -r 10 -n 10000000 -s 'def f(): None' 'f()' 
10000000 loops, best of 10: 0.209 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -r 10 -n 10000000 -s 'def f(): pass' 'f()' 
10000000 loops, best of 10: 0.178 usec per loop
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation & timing statistics, appreciate that!

Comment: @shuwnyuantee Glad to be of help. It should be noted that the profiling statistics are highly version-, device-, and platform-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

`pass` is explicit about what to you want. Python philosophy: *Explicit is better than implicit.*, see the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Some IDEs warn you if you write some code after `pass`, but not after `None`, so you have an extra check.  I don't know why python code doesn't warn about so obvious user error (I doesn't think user will use `pass` and write other instructions).